# What does "stakeholders on" mean?

Tags: meaning

> PR and Communications services to stakeholders **on** subway operations

Does it mean:

"Provide (...) services to (stakeholders of subway operations)

or

"Provide (...) services to (stakeholders) about subway operations

I think the former one is correct, but I want to be sure.

Comment: The rest of the sentence would be helpful; as it is, that's actually ambiguous phrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with your opinion, for the main reason that we don't say 'provide services on something' or 'provide services about something'. It's also not common to say 'stakeholders on something', but it makes more sense than the other options. The normal prepositions to use with 'stakeholders' are 'of' and 'in'.

The phrase is unclear due to the preposition 'on'. If it was talking about 'communications on subway operations' it would make sense. But the subject is not 'communications'. The subject is clearly 'services', which is part of the noun phrase 'PR and Communications services'.

In the end I would say that this doesn't appear to be standard English, although it's hard to say without the context. It might be a regional usage.